# Applying a function depending of index and column of a dataframe to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pybind11

I have a dataframe `df` whose index is `[x[0], ..., x[N]]` and column is `[y[0], ..., y[M]]` and whose data is a 2D array of `z[i,j]`'s.

I have a python function `def f(x, y, z)` of 3 float variables and I would like to calculate the 2d array of `f(x[i], y[j], z[i,j])`'s in the fastest way using numpy and/or pandas but I don't see how to do it.

I see the `df.transform` method but it doesn't seem to allow for lambdas that are dependent on index and column of `df` -- or at least I don't know how to provide such lambdas.

Details on `df` and `f` :

- How was my `df` obtained ? I created it during a 45 minutes computation using an intensive numerical python vectorized function on a grid with N = 5000 and M = 5000 and I "`to_csv`'ed" it. Now when I want to use it, I use `read_csv`.
- Now my function `f` is quite an involved numerical `C++` function that I exposed to python with pybind11 (I put the tag for sake of completness) and that I don't want to rewrite in a "numpy vectorizable fashion" for now as it is ultra-optimized and very fast unitarily. Given `x,y` the function `f` solves numerically (iterative root finder) an equation with parameters `x,y,z` and unknow `Z`, the root of the equation being `f(x,y,z)`.

Comment: apply a function to dataframe will be mostly as fast a loop for on each cell. But if the function can be written in a way to accept arrays and the operation inside be vectorized, then you`ll gain time. Can you give your function and some input data?

Comment: also, give the values for N et M, is it a big dataframe or a 100 index by 50 columns?

Comment: @Ben.T I will edit my question to elaborate a bit

Comment: @Ben.T OP edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this :

```
matrix = df_prices.values
x_matrix = np.tile(x, (y.size, 1)).transpose()
y_matrix = np.tile(y, (x.size, 1)) 
f_vect = np.frompyfunc(f, 3, 1)
res = f_vect (matrix , x_matrix , y_matrix )
```

Performance-wise it was optimal without having to meddle with vectorizing myself the ultra-optimized but not vectorized root solver f -- which by the way is a C++ function that I expose to python with pybind11.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'x'}).melt(var_name='y', value_name='z', id_vars='x')
```

It essentially transform the dataframe to the long format, making each row to have three entries: x, y and z.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: the melted dataframe would contain one data point (x, y, z) in each row. If you function is vectorized you could compute it directly.

Comment: But how would I evaluate my `f(x, y, z)` (taking doubles) on it in the most efficient way then ?

Comment: if your function takes in 3 inputs separately, then you would have to use a for loop to evaluate row by row

Comment: Ah ok, so no pure numpy (and or pandas) way avoiding for loops ?

Comment: It depends on your function. Most numpy operations can be vectorized. We would need the details of your function to know more.

Comment: And would my function be completely numpy vectorized, how would you proceed ?

Comment: You could just do `f(df.values)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewite the function, then using loop `for` to apply the function seems a easy way. you can do this

```
idx = df.index
cols = df.columns
vals = df.to_numpy()
r = [ 
  [f(x,y,z) for y, z in zip(cols, vals[i])]
   for i, x in enumerate(idx)
]
# if you want to recreate a dataframe
df_root = pd.DataFrame(data=r, index=idx, columns=cols)
```

there is a list comprehension on the index that includes a list comprehension on both  the columns and the values of the row  at the same time. `vals[i]` access the values from the row at position `i`. The result `r` is a list of length number of rows (N) and each item is a list of length number of columns (M). you don't need this structure especially but it is a easy way to build a dataframe with same index-columns as the original data.

Note that it will still be long, you have about 25 million operations to do, even if f is optimized.

Comment: And would I rewrite the function ? (Laughable, I know :))

Comment: @Olorin well there is no one solution for all. It depends on what the function is. If it is 10 lines of code you can try to rewrite, if it is 1000, not sure it is worth it. As long as you are limited by `f` taking only three scalars, then you will have hard time to speed it up compared to loop `for`. And `np.vectorize` is not  magical solution in case you come across. Why not using directly `C++` to open the csv and perform the operations? I never wrote in `C++` but I think it is faster overall. You can also look at `Numba` or `Cython`, but not sure about compatibility with C++ function